# VS2017 - How to configure project for remote debugging

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2017, raspberry-pi3

I want to create an MP3 player on my Raspberry Pi (OS: Raspbian). The problem is, that i don't have any experience with Linux programming, and I'm having a huge problem with project configuration, becouse of cross platform compiling. I want to add two liblaries:

- [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/)
- [libao](https://xiph.org/ao/)

I'm able to compile the code on linux machine with `gcc -O2 test.cpp -lmpg123`, but I can't force Visual Studio to make see those libs.

I'm also having a problem with using wiringPi lib while I'm trying to remote debugging my program, since I have to run it as root for GPIO configuration. Is there any way for any way to force Visual Studio to run my compiled code with root privilages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I come from a long history of C/C++/MFC/Windows programming with no Linux experience at all. I started programming for the Raspberry a year or so ago, when I got one from my son for my birthday. With a C/C++ history it's really not that hard, but you just have to read in a bit because on Linux a lot is the same, and a lot isn't :). Just read and read and in time, you're an experienced Linux programmer! It takes some time I'm afraid.

So, I'm sort of an experienced newbie on this I think :). I found a lot of info on [www.die.net](http://www.die.net) (and other Linux man pages). If you search there for a function, say printf(), look at the (3) pages - they explain how you should use 'm.

But although VS2017 does a really good job on this, it's not always going as smooth as you would like. Sometimes it's just necessary to reboot your Raspberry, restart VS and try again. The Linux cross-compiling is quite new in VS and isn't perfect yet.

A few tips:

- Use a Raspberry with a fresh Stretch image to start with. Of course after a **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade**.
- Set the debugger in Visual Studio to gdb instead of gdbserver. This will prevent certain debugging problems.
- Place all your source files (.h and .cpp) in the main folder of your project alongside the main.cpp. If you place them in different directories and then include in your project, you can debug your program but you won't be able to step through.
- Start simple and debug your program often when you're developing. Don't add too much code before your next check. In a cross-compile setup there are just a lot more things than normal that can (and will) go wrong.
- VS2017 has default Linux include files in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include*. If you need others, place them in a folder of you own and include the path.

With cross-compiling VS itself doesn't do any compiling, you use it to maintain your project. When the project has to be compiled, all necessary files are copied to the Raspberry and the compiler and linker there are invoked by VS.

On your question how to configure a project for remote debugging: it's probably best to start with the Blink example in Visual Studio 2017 (File, New, Project, Installed, Visual C++, Cross Platform, Linux => Blink). It should run without problems. From there, you can build further on your project.

In the Blink example, they use wiringPiSetupSys() and the remote command **gpio export 17 out** to run your program without sudo. I've found that changing that to wiringPiSetup() and disabling the remote command, it still is possible to run and debug the program. On the Raspberry I can run the program from it's folder by issuing **./[programname]**. If that doesn't work for you, you could run the program by issuing **sudo ./[programname]**.